# есть блоки как поставить их в строку?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

есть блоки как поставить их в строку

```css
.main_blocks div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_blocks">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3"></div>
  <div class="item4"></div>
  <div class="item5"></div>
  <div class="item6"></div>
  <div class="item7"></div>
  <div class="item8"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Указывать направление нужно не в самих блоков, а в родителя

```css
.main_blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.main_blocks div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_blocks">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3"></div>
  <div class="item4"></div>
  <div class="item5"></div>
  <div class="item6"></div>
  <div class="item7"></div>
  <div class="item8"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: есть ширина в 1000 px нужно те которые в строку не влезают на новую строчку ставились. Вообщем их 8 а в одной 4

Comment: @ВиталийСлободянюк задайте ширину `.main-block` и скажите ему `flex-wrap:wrap;`